# How can I make this boxplot using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I need to create a graph using ggplot, but I was only able to create it using the base R.

It's a survey I'm doing. Variable scores range from 0 to 100.

This is the boxplot I created using R Base:
[Boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKutQ.png)

```
    #My data looks like this:
Gender <- c("Man", "Man", "Woman", "Woman", "Man", "Woman", "Woman", "Man", "Woman", "Man")
V1 <- c(85, 100, 80, 70, 85, 85, 80, 70, 100, 80)
V2 <- c(92, 92, 84, 78, 80, 94, 100, 94, 100, 94)
V3 <- c(86, 80, 60, 53, 80, 73, 80, 73, 86, 93)
V4 <- c(80, 70, 20, 40, 60, 20, 100, 40, 60, 20)
V5 <- c(100, 90, 100, 80, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100)
boxplot(Dados$V1, Dados$V2, Dados$V3,  Dados$V4, Dados$V5, data = Dados, 
    horizontal = F, main = NULL, ylab = NULL, names = c("Sexismo", "LGBTfobia", "AmbUniver", "GenSexEns", "Valores"),
    col = c("darkred", "darkolivegreen4", "yellow3", "purple4", "darkorange3"), 
    cex.lab = 1.9, cex.axis = 2.7, cex = 1.5, cex.main = 2.8, lwd = 3, lty = "solid", bty = 7)
```

How can I do this using ggplot? I couldn't, because I can't put the Vs on the x-axis like I do with the boxplot on the base R. And how can I, in ggplot, put men and women side by side, since they are also components of the same variable "Gender"?

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the data into long format  using `tidyr::pivot_longer`

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Gender) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = name, colour = Gender), position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9))+
  scale_colour_manual(breaks = c("Woman", "Man"),
                      values = c("green", "gray30"))+
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"),
                    values = c("darkred", "darkolivegreen4", "yellow3", "purple4", "darkorange3"))+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Sexismo", "LGBTfobia", "AmbUniver", "GenSexEns", "Valores"))+
  guides(fill = 'none') +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

**data**

```
Gender <- c("Man", "Man", "Woman", "Woman", "Man", "Woman", "Woman", "Man", "Woman", "Man")
V1 <- c(85, 100, 80, 70, 85, 85, 80, 70, 100, 80)
V2 <- c(92, 92, 84, 78, 80, 94, 100, 94, 100, 94)
V3 <- c(86, 80, 60, 53, 80, 73, 80, 73, 86, 93)
V4 <- c(80, 70, 20, 40, 60, 20, 100, 40, 60, 20)
V5 <- c(100, 90, 100, 80, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100)

df <- data.frame(Gender, V1, V2, V3, V4, V5)
```